# Access document object in my contentScriptInjection in js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, code-injection, content-script

I am trying to build a chrome-extension, that modifies a viewed page.
Accessing its elements like $("body") isn't a problem, but since I want to use the querySelectorAll, I need the document-object.
And I've tried things like

```
var itemElements = $(document).querySelectorAll(".featured-item");
```

but it simply doesn't work. If I do it directly on the site via console, it works.

EDIT: By now I've figured it out. its by using only:

```
    var itemElements = document.querySelectorAll(".featured-item");
```